# Deployment Failed , Error: Cannot find module './connectionState'

Tags: deployment, render

I got Error: Cannot find module `'./connectionState'` while deploying my app.

[enter image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQFs2.png) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAAHL.png)[description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQFs2.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EnE1P.png)

```
My package.json :

{
  "engine": {
    "node": "18.13.0"
  }, 
  "name": "staypedia",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\"&& exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@mapbox/mapbox-sdk": "^0.15.3",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cloudinary": "^1.41.2",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "^4.4.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.9",
    "ejs-mate": "^4.0.0",
    "engine": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "joi": "^17.9.2",
    "jsdom": "^23.2.0",
    "method-override": "^3.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.4",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "multer-storage-cloudinary": "^4.0.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^8.0.0",
    "view": "^1.1.1"
  }
}
```

Hope someone could help me figure this out, thanks.

Hope someone could help me figure this out, thanks.